# Can't search dependencies via Android Studio 3.0 project structure

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide, android-studio-3.0

I use the Android Studio 3.0, when I tried adding a library via Android Studio 3.0

> project structure -> dependencies -> library dependency

My Android Studio is like this:

[image]

Comment: Fixed on v3.1, update your studio

Answer (score 1):

If you write down a fully-qualified dependency

*(like this):com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0*

When press an enter or click the 'ok'-cta, and after that, you click the 'ok' again,

Then the studio will add the dependency to your build.gradle file.
Sync your project, and that's all.

You are able to modify the scope before you add the new dependency.
Use implementation/annoitationProcessor/compileOnly/etc. as expected.
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)

But, I think it is a better way to handle(add and remove) all the dependencies in the build.gradle file directly, and use this window for double-check the already used dependency.

I hope, it helps you.